How to force hr separator using NSAttributedString to fill a requested width?
This is how I defined my separator:
extension NSAttributedString {
    static var separator: NSAttributedString {
        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .strikethroughStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
            .strikethroughColor: UIColor.lightGray,
        ]
        return NSAttributedString(string: "\n\r\u{00A0} \u{0009} \u{00A0}\n\n", attributes: attributes)
    }
}

And use it like this:
attributed.append(.separator)

The results is following:

How can I spread that line to, for example, 300 px?

Answer for given width equal 300. Separator is also centered on the screen.
static var separator: NSAttributedString {
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 0
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
    paragraphStyle.tabStops = [NSTextTab(textAlignment: .center, location: 300, options: [:])] //here you can define the width of separator
    let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .strikethroughStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
        .strikethroughColor: UIColor.black.alpha(0.2),
        .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
    ]
    return NSAttributedString(string: "\n\u{00a0}\t\n", attributes: attributes)
}


